# Regular expression search term?

Tags: regex

Im just looking for a search term in Regular expression that will find all occurrences of measurements in a sentence?

For instance say im looking for Litres (L)?

- 3l Bin
- 2L xxx
- 2l    xxxxx
- 2l[just spaces]

So there is a number followed by a L or l followed by 1 or many spaces and maybe more text?

So far i have "**\d+[l] +**" 
but this doesn't capture all variances like '2L[more than one space]xxxxx'

The end goal is to correct and standardise all text, ie all L's in upper case when in a measurement!

Also i know i could easily use instr() functions but wanted to try RegEx.

Cheers

Comment: do you have a finite list of measurements or how do you knkow what is and isn't a measure?

Comment: share your tried code

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: We can't help you write code to do something without first knowing your definition of the problem.  How do you define "measurement"?

Comment: Number + L or l + space + any or no text 

Thanks

Comment: There are multiple ways to go about this, but it depends on your regex flavour... You can use `\b(\d+)l ` and replace with `$1L ` (note regex and replacement has a space at the end). You can use `(?:^|(?<=\D))(\d+)l ` which only works in some regex flavours and ensure what precedes the digit is not a digit (this is better than the first regex, but less supported). There's also `(?:^|(?<=\D))\d+\Kl(?= )` and replace with `L`, which is probably the easiest replacement ever (more complicated regex), but this has even less support across regex flavours. What regex flavour?

Comment: Also, I'd suggest not capturing what follows after the litre string. The reason is that you might have a string like `From 3l to 6l` and you won't correct the second instance of `6l` since you'll catch it in the first capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(\d+)[lL]\s+(.*)**

- Group 1 contains the number of liters (only the number)
- Group 2 the following text (not sure if this was required)

Matches:

- 3L foo
- 2l foo
- 123213l      foo

Ignores:

- l foo
- 3lfoo

Comment: will that allow for the space after the L? 
it must have a Space after to be considered a litre measurement.. 
i.e.....
Number + L or l + space + any or no text
Thanks

Comment: Added \s+ for whitespaces

Comment: `[l|L]` makes no sense in terms of this question btw. It should be `[lL]`, but also, there's no point in capturing the `L` since the OP is looking to convert them all to uppercase, which simply means that if you're catching `L`, you're doing additional tasks for no reason.

Comment: "(\d+[l|L]\s+)" works (didnt matter if there anything after the '[number]L[space]' so sorry for misleading! opps)

it works for all terms except the "3L" in a sentence on its own or at the end of a sentence i.e. no space after the "3L"

Comment: ctwheels, im looking to capture ALL to begin with then optimise, im using this as a learning exercise, ive used reg ex off and on a little in my 20+ yrs coding, but think its about time to understand the search terms and expressions more! :)

Comment: Using \s* instead of \s+ will match "3L", but will also match "3Lfoo". I think you'll need some kind of look ahead to prevent matching the latter.

Comment: thanks Greg.. the only scenario it doesn't cover and one im not really worried about is just a sentence like "3L" with no other text..
cheers

Comment: @GlenRichmond it works, but what I'm saying is that `|` should **NOT** be in the set `[]`. It will give you incorrect results given an odd string. It will match `3| ` (note that it's the `|` character and not the letter `l` or `L`).

Comment: @ctwheels I've removed the pipe from the regex.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `(\d+(\.\d+)?)[lL]\s.+`
tested with:

> 3l Bin works
>
> 2L xxx works
>
> 2l xxxxx works
>
> 2l[just spaces] works
>
> 33.33343l works
>
> 33 l (no match)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4mWryV/3)